# How to precache a SVG image from a SVG string?

Tags: string, flutter, svg, caching

I'm already using the `precachePicture` function from the `flutter_svg` library, to load svg assets :

```
Future<void> loadPictures() async {
  await precachePicture(
    ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, 'assets/graphic/two_people.svg'),
    context,
  ); 
}
```

However i have some raw svg string (more complexe than this one) that need to be precached too

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 240 240"><polygon points="120 8.9 147.31 93.45 236.99 93.45 164.41 146.38 191.77 231.09 120 178.76 48.23 231.09 75.59 146.37 3.01 93.45 92.69 93.45 120 8.9" fill="#f8d64e"/></svg>
```

How can one precache a SVG image from a SVG string ?

Comment: can you convert the string to a data url and then pass that to ExactAssetPicture?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to managed this with a data url as you said, but couldn't do it. I finally found the solution, which i've just posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i finally found the solution:

```
svgString = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 240 240"><polygon points="120 8.9 147.31 93.45 236.99 93.45 164.41 146.38 191.77 231.09 120 178.76 48.23 231.09 75.59 146.37 3.01 93.45 92.69 93.45 120 8.9" fill="#f8d64e"/></svg>';

Future<void> loadSvgPictureFromSvgString() async {
  await precachePicture(
            StringPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, svgString), context); //context or null
}
```

Now, when you call `SvgPicture.string(svgString)` the image would already be precached, so no delay of rendering if the svgString is a bit complexe.

Answer (score 2):

In `flutter_svg` 2.x `precachePicture` was dropped!

Now you have to preload like this:

```
 final SvgAssetLoader loader = SvgAssetLoader('assets/mypicture.svg');
 await svg.cache.putIfAbsent(loader.cacheKey(null), () => loader.loadBytes(null));
```

I build a loop around all my svg images in a loading screen:

```
for (String image in Assets.svgImages.values) {
     final SvgAssetLoader loader = SvgAssetLoader(image);
     await svg.cache.putIfAbsent(loader.cacheKey(null), () => loader.loadBytes(null));
}
```

`Assets.svgImages.values` is a `List<String>` generated with `flutter_gen` containing all svg file paths in asset folder :-)